# Removing data:application/x-font-ttf and data:application/font-woff from Semantic-UI CSS?

Tags: css, webpack, fonts, semantic-ui

I'm using React Semantic UI with Webpack, and the context I'm deploying to does not allow self-embedded fonts (data:application/x-font-ttf), but it does allow relative path fonts, which results in the errors:

`Refused to load the font 'data:application/x-font-ttf;charset=utf-8;base64[...]
because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "font-src https://locationofmyapp.com https://fonts.googleapis.com https://fonts.gstatic.com".`

What's the quickest/cleanest toolset to use to either totally remove the `data:application/font-woff` and `data:application/x-font-ttf` components from the stylesheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone else comes across this, the problem is that there's a typo in Semantic-UI.

Several of the files contain a double semi-colon `;;`

To fix the issue:

1. Remove every file containing the double semi-colon ;;

   - `\node_modules\semantic-ui-css\components\step.min.css`
   - `\node_modules\semantic-ui-css\components\step.css`
   - `\node_modules\semantic-ui-css\semantic.min.css`
   - `\node_modules\semantic-ui-css\semantic.css`
2. Delete the `node_modules` cache folders:

   - `\node_modules\.cache\default-development`
   - `\node_modules\.cache\babel-loader`
3. Restart the dev server (`yarn start` or `npm start`)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the tool to solve your problem, but I had a application with the same problem. I just get the font-face directive from the source of the fonts and downloaded the fonts woof2 archives, than I pointed the semantic-ui to get the fonts from my local fonts folder, then I gave authorization to execute it from there in my server: 

`font-src 'self' data:`

This way I could get the best from the two words.
data:application/x-font-ttf make fonts load fast and your application will gain speed and the security is maintained, but you must ensure that it loads from a secure source.